# How to show text together with an icon in Contextual Action Bar / ActionMode?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu, android-actionmode

Using the Action Bar, I can add icons with text as below picture shows.

[image]

This is achieved like this

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

How do I achieve this in my [Contextual Action Bar (CAB)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB)?

I've tried like this:

```
<item
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
    android:id="@+id/context_delete"
    android:title="@string/context_delete" />
```

But this only results in my CAB showing icons only, even on 7" tablets with plenty of space.

[image]

### Question

How do I add the icon+text to my CAB, as I've done with my Action Bar in the picture above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAB and support library do not get along.

You need to use the default android namespace to get the text values to show up:

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"/>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work when using the support action mode?